# Displaying a citation list with many authors on mobile

Tags: mobile, lists, material-design

I'm working on a project which will display university research paper citations, some of which will have up to 5000 authors (yeah, I know!).

There are multiple places we need to display a full citation for confirmation purposes, and we need to explicitly display anything from 1 to 5000 authors in a usable way on mobile, and also using Material Design.

Anyone else tackled a usability case like this before?

Comment: do you have a mock of what you've been thinking of so far? It would be good to see an example of what you're working on, so the community can be more specific.

Comment: Not sharable (all behind firewalls) but Ive been experimenting with ellipsising and expanding the container on mouseover (not good for mobile, although an onTouch thing could apply)... trying a scrolling div...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going on a whim here but I think almost nobody actually wants to view 5000 authors in a list. I think possible workflows are:

1. Searching for a certain name (maybe your own, or a few names) in the list
2. Getting the whole list for copying/verifying against your own 5000 list

I would solve these workflows with two interaction elements: As soon as there are more than X authors, display a Search-Field and a download-button. The download-button opens the whole list as a simple text-file with all authors (so you can easily copy/save/print/edit it) - and the searchfield will display results as you type so you can easily verify if certain names are in the list.

Comment: Thank you for that. 

Sadly, this is for a citation - so the authors need to be displayed/selectable/copyable - Im beginning to think just having a resizing div container might be the solution....

Comment: Copyable can be solved with a button **copy full list to clipboard** without having to display the full list

Comment: For citations you can also provide a button in each line to generate the whole citation string to the clipboard in one of several standard format used in papers in your field

Answer (score 2):

Just hide the authors until the user hits "Show authors". 
Provide filters so the user can sort the authors, maybe even add a search bar in cases where for example more then 20 authors are listed so the user can search by name and/or other keywords.

You can include pagination as well to shorten the list.

Just treat it like any other big data table.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the information that the user would like to see. Having worked in a university, it is important to know who is the most important author of the research paper citation. In the case that there isn't one, then it is better to display them alphabetically.

My proposal is to design it with an expandable list, as you can see in the following image.

[image: Expandable list]